# tabbing in textarea using selenium sendkeys

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using the Sendkeys method in selenium trying to fill out a text are. The text has a `\t`. In this scenario, it will only paste the text before the `\t` and the rest of the text is not pasted. I am assuming this is because it has lost focus. For example:

```
elem.SendKeys("howard \t was here");
```

The textarea will only have howard in it. Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is expected.

You could try using spaces instead, or if you really need tabs you could set the textarea content via javascript snippet which you pass in to seleniums execute http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/index.html